# Why doesn`t work Crystal Reports XI with parameter?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

community,
I have a tickler.
In the report with ADO (OLE DB connection) appears next error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWgUh.png)
Below you can see partly example of a command.
[Command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TepG.png)
There is no syntactic error near the SET keyword.
When I manually select an empty string for CLIENT_NUM everything works fine.
Is anyone have suggestions?

I tried to change the empty string to 'all' but this doesn`t resolve my problem.
In CR UI I tried many times with the default value and without.
Maybe it depends on version of the Native Client?

Comment: It can be a problem with a commented line. Try to change two dashes "--" to "/*  */". Or just remover it at all.
Also check "C" in client. Sometimes it can be Russian С. Not sure if Crystal report highlights such things.

Comment: I fyou provide the code and errro message in text instead of picture I guess you'll have better chance that someone will answer you

Comment: It was a schoolboy error. 
If i want to use client number it works, but if I want to get result for all clients and use empty string  - parameter must be concluded in single quotes.
Like this '{?CLIENT_NUM}' instead of this {?CLIENT_NUM}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a basic error. If I want to use the client number, it works; but if I want to get results for all clients and use an empty string, the parameter must be concluded in single quotes. Like `{?CLIENT_NUM}` instead of `{?CLIENT_NUM}`.